# Access violation after going out of a RTTI-related function: Result disappears

Tags: delphi, rtti

Previously I had one function to get object property through RTTI and set it's value. Now I decided to split it up in `TRTTI.GetObjProp` and `TRTTI.SetObjPropValue` in order to cache value returned by `TRTTI.GetObjProp` and speed up data processing.

Strange things happen after that. First of all, I suddenly noticed that `ctx.GetType` works and has always worked although I never initialized the `ctx` variable. Ok, if I initialize it with `TRttiContext.Create()`, nothing changes in the second weirdness:

I call the `TRTTI.GetObjProp` function and as long as I am in this function, `Result` is defined, and I can request it's properties with debugger. When I go out of the function, I try to request the same properties of `rprop` variable and get Access Violation error. According to debugger, `rprop` is defined.

```
procedure TConfManager._setValue(indicator: TComponent; name: string; value: OleVariant);
var
  rprop: TRttiProperty;
begin
  rprop := TRTTI.GetObjProp(indicator, name);
  //Access violation here when I try to use rprop
  TRTTI.SetObjPropValue(indicator, rprop, value);
end;

class function TRTTI.GetObjProp(obj: TObject; propName: string): TRttiProperty;
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  rtyp: TRttiType;
begin
  if obj = nil then Exit(nil);
  rtyp := ctx.GetType(obj.ClassType);
  Result := rtyp.GetProperty(propName);
end;
```

Why the function result is properly defined when I am in the function, but isn't properly defined when I go out of it?

Comment: Try to declare the `ctx` as a global variable. It's a record and does not need creation.

Comment: Declaring the `ctx` as a global variable helped to solve Access Violation!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TRttiProperty` instance is owned by the `TRttiContext` object. When your local variable `ctx` leaves scope, that `TRttiContext` object is destroyed, taking with it all the objects it owns, including your `TRttiProperty` instance.

You need to make sure that the `TRttiContext` object that owns any RTTI objects that you use lives at least as long as any references to those owned objects. The simplest way to achieve that is probably to make the `TRttiContext` object be a global variable.